# Copy a embedded message onto another channel (discordjs)

Tags: discord.js

I've seen questions that look like it, but not quite what I mean.
I have a bot that copies the bot logs from one server, and pastes it into another.

Issue is, the logs are made by mee6, and mee6 embeds it's messages.
I want it to collect the embeded message completely, and paste it into another channel. How do I do that?

Current code:

```
let filter = m => !m.author.user;
let collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(listenChannel, filter);
collector.on('collect', (message, col) => {
    var collected = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .addField(message.author.username, message.content)
    .setColor(0xffa114)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('KorBot', 'https://i.imgur.com/AvLp2YD.png');
    pasteChannel.send(collected)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Any received message has the `embeds` property which is an array of embeds. It might be wise to check on the length of that array before deciding how to process the message's content.